# How to try-except block exit when try is working

Tags: python, selenium

The code I have works. The last for loop gets reached and `choice.click()` gets clicked on. The question I have is why the except block gets executed even though the:

```
            if choice.text == call_resource:
                choice.click()
                break
```

piece of the code is reached and the `choice.click()` portion works?

```
def select_choice(driver, resource_tag): 
    try:
        call_resource = None
        access_data = common.retrieve_tag_access_data()
        for row in access_data["access_data"]:
            if str(row["id"]) == resource_tag:
                call_resource = row["row_tag"]["name"]
                break
        if call_resource is None:
            access_data = common.retrieve_fixture_access_data()
            for row in access_data["access_data"]:
                if str(row["id"]) == resource_tag:
                    call_resource = row["row_tag"]["name"]
                    break
        menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul[role='listgrid']")
        choices = menu.find_elements_by_css_selector("li[role='choices']")
        for choice in choices:
            if choice.text == call_resource:
                choice.click()
                break
    except:
        error(logger, "unable to select choice")
        pass
```

Because the last for loop works, shouldn't it `break` entirely out of the function after `choice.click()` without executing the `except:` portion of the code?

Comment: Please see [mre]. We have no way of verifying if this code actually does work.

Comment: If `choice.click()` executes successfully, then the `except` block should not trigger.  something else must be happening.  Temporarily take out the try/except statements and let the error happen, just so you can see exactly where it is.

Comment: `break` only breaks out of the loop, whether it's a for loop or while loop. 
so in your code it runs the `for choice in choices:` loop, and breaks the loop, then continues onto the next portion of code

Comment: @colk84 He's talking about the break in the very last loop.

Comment: @JohnGordon i misread that. edited my comment. still, the same applies

Comment: @colk84 but there's no next portion of the code, so it should break completely from the function?

Comment: @JohnGordon, that's what I thought. It should break after succefully doing `choice.click()` and thus avoid `except`. Must be something outside the function affecting the function.

Comment: if it catches an issue in the `try` section. it will cause it to run the `except` portion of code. like @Amit Sides said. find the problem and it shouldn't run the code after the last forloop

Comment: @init200 add a `print` right after the last for loop, not inside of it. it will run all the code up until there;s an issue. i'm betting it wont print

Comment: @colk84 indeed using `print` showed the `menu =` selector was not producing a result and got overlooked. This try-except block is now working correctly.

Comment: This is the problem with the catch-all exception. You should never do that, since it is masking any and all errors. At least pull the error out with sys.exc_info() and print that.

Answer (score 1):

The `except:` portion will run only if an Exception occurred inside the `try` block. You should change the `except:` line to something like `except Exception as e:` and print the variable `e` in some way so you can discover what the problem is.

Comment: While useful, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
choices = menu.find_elements_by_css_selector("li[role='choices']")
for choice in choices:
     if choice.text == call_resource:
        choice.click()
        break
```

Could be replaced with since your only trying to click one element with a certain text why not just **try** to find it. If it errors out it will go to the exception you provided.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f"//li[@role='choices' and contains(text(),{call_resource})]").click()
```

Also use to find errors use the following.

```
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking here. This is alternate way, however it still does not address the original issue reported on this thread.

Comment: The break is unnecessary to what he actually wants to do. He just wants to click on an element with that text.

Comment: it isn't. how will you come out of the loop once certain conditions are met?

Comment: The break only works on the for loop. Without the for loop it'll immediately go out. If it fails it'll go to the except.